# How do I set the number of default parallel jobs [-j 4] for Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is there a way to set cargo to default add `-j 4` to all the calls?

As workaround I've used this script:

`cargoj4`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cargo "$1" -j 4
```

but this does not always work (I forget to call it :-\ or I have scripts in the project that use `cargo` and I cannot modify them).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a [`config.toml`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) to define parallel jobs. You need to create `.cargo/config.toml`. You can define it globally or per project, depending on your needs.

And then you just need to add

```
[build]
jobs = 4                      # number of parallel jobs, defaults to # of CPUs
```

You also have the possiblity of creating an `alias` for your command, which you would put in the same file:

```
[alias]
j4 = "build -j 4"
```

And then you can just invoke it as `cargo j4`

Answer (score 3):

You can set this in `cargo` configuration file. You can create a config file in `$HOME/.cargo/config.toml` with the configuration you need.

```
[build]
jobs = 4 # number of parallel jobs, defaults to # of CPUs
```

Read more about [Hierarchical structure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#hierarchical-structure), [Configuration format](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#configuration-format) and [Jobs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#buildjobs) options [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html).